# How to get string from chain of types?

Tags: swift

I have server APIs divided on groups. I try to build struct to have an ability get api in string form.

For example i tried something like these

```
struct ServerApi {
    enum Auth {
        case login
        case logout
        
        var string: String {
            "/\(Self.self)".lowercased() + "/\(self)"
        }
    }
    enum App {
        case version
        case webapiVersion
        case buildInfo
        
        var string: String {
            "/\(Self.self)".lowercased() + "/\(self)"
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    enum GroupA {
        case versionA
        case webapiVersionA
        case buildInfoA
        
        var string: String {
            "/\(Self.self)".lowercased() + "/\(self)"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get string fully described path of the enum property without writhing `string` computed property in each enum?

Comment: By the way, repeated concatenation can be pretty slow for the type checker. You might want to consider using string interpolation like `"/\(String(describing: Self.self).lowercased())/\(self)"`, especially if the number of parts increases

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/protocols#Protocol-Extensions

```swift
protocol string { }
extension string {
  var string: String {
    "/\(Self.self)".lowercased() + "/\(self)"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help to explain how to apply this `string` protocol to the OP's struct/enums.